# <?php mail() won't work

Tags: php, parsing

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
$to = 'somebody@once.told.me'; 
$subject = 'the world was gonna roll me'; 
$user = $_POST['user'];
$comment = $_POST['comment']; 
$tel = $_POST['tel']; 
$email = $_POST['mail']; 


$message = "From " . $user . "\r\n" . 
"Im not the sharpest tool in the shed" . "\r\n" . 
"Addidtional details " . "\r\n" . 
$email . "\r\n" . 
$tel;} 

if ($_POST){ 
mail($to, $subject ,$message); 
$feedback = 'she was looking kind of dumb'; } 
?>
```

> Now it's a bit more readable, after switching the breaks and appling everything I needed, it just stopped sending to the email as before. It sends the feedback and nothing else. 
>   **Do you know why?**

Comment: The email is most likely sent as HTML, thus you need to send <br /> instead.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @urfusion Code was there but not shown. Edited it.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy edited, Code now there.

Comment: you have a missing dot between `"/r/n" "additional contact:"`

Comment: anyway, use \ instead of /. Line break is `\n`, but in HTML `<br>`. And you should not echo it, put it into your string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send it by an HTML mail, try this

```
$message = "form:" . $user . "\r\n<br>" .
$comment . "\r\n<br>" 
         . "additional contact:" . $email . $tel;
```

Comment: <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "somebody@once.told.me";
$subject = "the world was gonna roll me";
$user = $_POST['user'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];

$message = "מ" . $user . "\r\n" .
"Im not the sharpest tool in the shed"
. "\r\n" . "לפרטים נוספים"
. "\r\n" . $email 
. "\r\n" . $tel;
}

if ($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject ,$message);
   $feedback = 'she was looking kind of dumb';
} ?>     **I tried to launch it now, and although it works it doesnt send, do you know why?**

Comment: it is totally unreadble here. please edit your post, create an UPDATE section and post it there.